# Predict continuous variable from factor variables and dates/time series

Tags: r, machine-learning, self-study, categorical-data, prediction

I would like to know the best way, and ideally also less optimal ways, to predict, for "next week", the health index (outc_health_index) of subjects (subject_id), based on daily data (date) on whether they have gone jogging or not (pred_went_jogging) and on whether they did meditation or not (pred_did_meditation)

I am stuck at the very beginning, before statistics and coding, I do not know whether I can ignore the dates and so avoid getting into time series that I do not well and would avoid if possible. 
(Note that this is an exercise to get back in contact with statistic&C so I have some freedom)

These are the data

```
set.seed(1000); N <- 100

# generate sample data
subject_id <- sample(1:7, size = N, replace = TRUE)
pred_went_jogging <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
pred_did_meditation <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2001/06/01'), as.Date('2002/12/12'), by="day"), N)
date <- date[order(date)]
outc_health_index <- rnorm(N)
# collect in data frame
df <- data.frame(subject_id, pred_went_jogging
  ,pred_did_meditation,date,outc_health_index)

# make subject id character
df$subject_id <- as.character(df$subject_id)
```

head(df, n=3)

```
  subject_id pred_went_jogging pred_did_meditation       date outc_health_index
1          3                 1                   0 2001-06-05         0.9182955
2          6                 0                   0 2001-06-07         0.7304148
3          1                 0                   1 2001-06-19        -1.6822627
```

Comment: How is the health index calculated? What kind of statistical properties can be assumed for this variable? It's also not clear from your question whether you have a time series of `outc_health_index` values and corresponding predictor values.

Comment: outc_health_index is just observed, assume it normally distributed (just updated the sample code) the goal is to understand how meditation and jogging affect it, and understand how to create a predictive model, with whatever kind of approach –

Comment: Something called an "index" is usually not "just observed" but at least normalized on some scale. Indices are generally not from a normal distribution. The properties of this variable are important for the choice of method. You also have not confirmed that you have time series for each individual.

Comment: I'm sorry I am unable to provide more info because this is an "exercise" and I don't have further info besides what I provided and what is deducible from the real word context of the exercise

Comment: If this is an exercise you should add the self-study tag. Additionally, in the case of self-study this website encourages you to show what you already know and have tried (this will make clear where any answer should start off from). Further, self-study requires you to find the answer yourself, possibly with the help of those on this website. Therefore, the answer might not be provided, but only hinted at.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the self study tag.
Regarding your "self-study requires your 
to find the answer yourself, possibly with the help of those on this website" obviously I agree with it and have tried to find the answe myself without success.

Do you have some answer or other comments that help me move towards finding the solution or at least improving on current impasse?

Comment: I did not mean to suggest you have not put effort into finding an answer. Pardon me if you think so. However, the thing is, it is not clear what you've already tried, or what you have come to understand about the question you are putting forward. Some pointers: Are you familiar with regression modelling? Have you heard about repeated measures and multilevel modelling? Do you know how to work with dates in these models (e.g. setting the starting date to zero)? etc...

Comment: Didn'try much because I was stuck on the first point, ... basic real world analysis (even though this is an underspecified exercise), 
my guess is that dates are not (very) meaningful and so I can avoid time-series and just analyze the two binary predictors (didn't learn time series well so far, seem to require some care so would avoid them if not strictly necessary). 
I am familiar with regression and basic machine learning, though have been away from them for some months and need to refresh them. This exercise is my first step "restarting" learning

Comment: My guess is that time series analysis is extremely necessary, but you have not confirmed whether you have indeed time series.

Comment: Will spend a couple of days trying to re-study them decently and then get back to exercise. Thanks.